# Tkinter: Output text box contents with newline ending

Tags: python, windows, text, tkinter, pyperclip

I am trying to create a program that I can input notes for work and output to a text file and copy to clipboard to post into a notes template.

When I run this program the text box input(entry4) is copied to the clipboard in a single line. I.E.`(example example example)`

I would like it to be copied to the clipboard as

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Here is the program code.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip
import datetime


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Hector's Notes Program")
root.iconbitmap("TDS.ico")

time = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %dth %B %Y %I:%M%p"))
nl = "\r\n"

def printInfo():
    file = open("C:\\Users\\Hector\\Desktop\\Test.txt", "a")
    file.write(nl + time + nl)
    file.write(q1 + nl)
    file.write(entry1.get() + nl)
    file.write(q2 + nl)
    file.write(entry2.get() + nl)
    file.write(q3 + nl)
    file.write(entry3.get() + nl)
    file.write(q4 + nl)
    file.write(entry4.get("1.0", 'end-1c') + nl)
    file.write(q5 + nl)
    file.write(entry5.get() + nl)
    file.write(q6 + nl)
    file.write(entry6.get() + nl)
    file.write(nl)
    file.close()
    results = q1 + "\r\n" + entry1.get() + "\r\n" + q2 + "\r\n" + entry2.get() + "\r\n" + q3 + "\r\n" + entry3.get() + "\r\n" + q4 + "\r\n" + entry4.get("1.0", 'end-1c') + "\r\n" + q5 + "\r\n" + entry5.get() + "\r\n" + q6 + "\r\n" + entry6.get()
    print(results)
    pyperclip.copy(results)


q1 = "Customer Name:"
q2 = "Contact Number:"
q3 = "Customer Reporting:"
q4 = "Troubleshooting done:"
q5 = "Is the issue resolved / Next step?"
q6 = "UTS Ticket #"

label1 = Label(root, text=q1)
label2 = Label(root, text=q2)
label3 = Label(root, text=q3)
label4 = Label(root, text=q4)
label5 = Label(root, text=q5)
label6 = Label(root, text=q6)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry3 = Entry(root)
entry4 = Text(root, width=40, height=10)
entry5 = Entry(root)
entry6 = Entry(root)

entry1.focus_set()

label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
label4.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=S)
label5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)
label6.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=E)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry4.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
entry5.grid(row=5, column=1)
entry6.grid(row=6, column=1)


button1 = Button(root, text="Print Notes", command=printInfo)
button1.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: @Hector Marroquin: `tkinter` clipboard option no are sufficient?

Comment: @Clodion I was unaware that tkinter had it's own clipboard tool. I have figured out how to do this now. Thank you so much for the advice it was a great help!